# Domain-member Win7 system can't access Ubuntu share

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, network-shares, samba

I have a home network with the following computers:

- Windows XP SP3 (workgroup: MSHOME)
- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Samba, workgroup: MSHOME)
- Windows 7 Ultimate company laptop (domain: XYZ)

#### XP <--> Ubuntu works fine

Both XP and Ubuntu are on the same workgroup, and they can access each other's shares just fine.

#### Win 7 <--> XP works fine

My Win 7 work laptop (member of a domain) can also access shares on the XP box (using credentials `<hostname>\<username>` and `<password>`), even though the laptop is not a member of the MSHOME workgroup.

#### Win 7 <--> Ubuntu ... not so much

For some reason, I can't access shares on the Ubuntu box from my laptop. I can *see* the shares if I type `\\<hostname>\` into Win7 Explorer. However, clicking on a displayed share in Explorer produces a credentials prompt, and no matter what I enter, I get a *permission denied* message.

*Interestingly, I get a slightly different error message if I type in an intentionally incorrect password, so I believe things are working up to a point...*

The Samba Server Configuration app in Ubuntu has some different Authentication Mode settings. The default is *User*, and I haven't changed it.

Has anyone dealt with this configuration (Win7-domain / Samba-workgroup)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been searching online and trying various things, but no joy. I don't know how to see what's actually happening behind the scenes, so it's just down to trying every combination I can think of until it works...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the Windows 7 laptop is automatically adding domain XYZ to the username.  Have you checked the logs on the Samba server to see what it's reporting?